# how to make a border on a css-only created image

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I have created a ribbon with css only. Now i want to make a 1px grey border around it. But the left and right side of the image are created already with a css border. is this possible to do that?

The image should look like this (you see the 1 px grey border):

[image]

This is the html and css i use to create the image:

```css
.yellow-ribbon-top-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 30px 0 0;
  border-color: #eedc08 transparent transparent transparent;
  float: left;
}

.yellow-ribbon-mid {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eedc08;
}

.yellow-ribbon-bottom-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 30px 30px;
  float: left;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eedc08 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-ribbon-bottom-right"></div>
<div class="yellow-ribbon-mid"></div>
<div class="yellow-ribbon-top-left"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify you code by using [**skew** transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew) then you can easily adjust border:

```css
.yellow-ribbon {
   width: 120px;
   height: 30px;  
   margin:20px;
   background-color: #eedc08;
   border:1px solid #000;
   transform:skew(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-ribbon">

</div>
```

---

By the way if you want to keep your actual code you can rely on pseudo-element like this *(but i **don't recommend** this solution as it makes the code even more complicated and we have above a simple one)*:

```css
.yellow-ribbon-top-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 30px 0 0;
  border-color: #eedc08 transparent transparent transparent;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}


/* create border around the left part */

.yellow-ribbon-top-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 32px 32px 0 0;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: -1px;
  z-index:-1
}
/* */

.yellow-ribbon-mid {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eedc08;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.yellow-ribbon-bottom-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 30px 30px;
  float: left;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eedc08 transparent;
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
}
/* create border around the right part */

.yellow-ribbon-bottom-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 32px 32px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
  top: -1px;
    right: 0;
  z-index:-1
}
/* */
```

```html
<div class="yellow-ribbon-bottom-right"></div>
<div class="yellow-ribbon-mid"></div>
<div class="yellow-ribbon-top-left"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks for the answer

Comment: @JackMaessen i also added another alternative base on your code, but i recommand you to go with the easier one of course ;)

Comment: I prefer the `transfor:skew` you mentioned. Its much easier to deal with it

Comment: @JackMaessen yes me too i prefer it, but i added another alternative i case you will be creating such shape and you don't have possibility of skewing ... if for example both triangle where the same in both sides ;)